# GL_TRIANGLE_FAN in iOS Metal

Tags: ios, metal

I'm looking for alternative of `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` in Metal.

I found only `MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle` or `MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangleStrip`. How can I draw circle with `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` in iOS Metal?

Comment: Unfortunately Metal does not support triangle fans. You will need to draw your vertices as one of the other primitive types that you mention. This will mean modifying your vertices or indices to match that topology.

Comment: This is such a shame, porting a Vulkan app making massive use of triangles fan is very complicated... Any idea why this key feature is still missing in Metal ?